# Window That Keeps Aggregated Results In Memory

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I'm using siddhi v4.1.10 in order to  create long running java standalone app that will process data from multiple files, aggregate it and send results into message broker. Approximately there will be **90 GB of files per day** with 130 millions of records (up to 100 000 events per minute). Each event created from file recod has ~30 fields.

Ex:

*define stream FileStream (time double, user_ip string, status string, bytes int, http_method string, url string, duration int,  ....);*

Application should be able to run **hundreds of queries** that aggregate data for 1min, 5min, 10 min batches based on time from logfile.

Ex:

*from FileStream#window.externalTimeBatch(time, 60 seconds) 
SELECT time, account_id, status_code, sum(bytes) AS bytes, count(requests) AS requests GROUP BY account_id, status_code, time insert into rabbtmqstream*

The problem is that batch window keeps events in memory until the time is up. But I need a system that can aggregate events over time periods without retaining any events in memory. Is it possible with siddhi?
I thought about OutputRateLimiter but it's not possible to extend it.
Please advise.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate a bit more on your requirement? 1. What is the input to the window? 2. What is the aggregation you'd like to do?
 3. What should be the output of the window?

Comment: Also, please mention the Siddhi version or the version of the WSO2 product you're using.

Comment: Hi @Dilini, I've updated my post with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Siddhi 4.x version. This will not store the events in-memory when aggregations are done via [timeBatch](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#timebatch-window) windows. In this case, it will only keep the running aggregate values in memory

Alternatively, you can also use [aggregators](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#incremental-aggregation) to aggregate values with the use of both in-memory and database.

Comment: ExternalTimeBatchWindowProcessor stores events in memory (siddhi v4.1.10)